# Where is the graveyard in Sims Medieval?

Tags: windows-phone, sims-medieval

While searching the web for potential sources of mushrooms in the game, I often come across references to the graveyard. I browsed around the map numerous times, but could not locate anything of that description. I even tried looking around the church thinking that's where a graveyard would be found traditionally, but no. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have to build one before it exists? (Note: I have only played traditional Sims for PC, not Sims Medieval on any platform)

Comment: No. You don't get to build buildings in this game. However, certain areas get unlocked after completing a quest. So it might be this, but I have no idea which quest that would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graveyard is not available initially. You need to have finished the second main quest of any of the quest lines (Charitable Guy II in my case) before it becomes available along with the castle.